# How to disable sending default emails when a user place an order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bigcommerce

I am working on a Third party application where I want to send customized template emails to user using webhooks when user place order or shipment gets created.

Is it possible to prohibit system to send email to user who place order and instead of that just fire an event to a third party app(using a webhook) so that that third party app will send email to that user with required and customized new details in new email template(which is not available in default variables of email templates)?

Any solution for this? Please

Comment: Is is straightforward to send emails if you setup the email server.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

There's two options. One enables you to prevent emails from being sent and the other repurposes the initial default email. There isn't currently a way to disable the email from being sent as the setting doesn't existing in BigCommerce.

**Option 1**

---

Set up an SMTP server and configure mail relay rules

SendGrid covers some good basics on what [mail relay](https://sendgrid.com/blog/smtp-relay-service-basics/) is. BigCommerce has a support article for [connecting your store to a custom SMTP server](https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Using-a-Custom-SMTP-Server/). You can also see more in the instructions from Microsoft on [how to configure mail relay rules](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277329.aspx) for Exchange.

Overall, this option is more complex.

**Option 2**

---

Conversio has a [quick and easy guide](https://docs.conversio.com/docs/disabling-bigcommerces-default-order-confirmation) on replacing the content of the default emails. It isn't the ideal solution, but it is less confusing than sending two receipts.